# JSON file with subkeys and subvalues in it

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a json file which looks like this:

```
{"people": [{"name": "carlota", "birthday": "11/12/1945"}, 
            {"name": "mariana", "birthday": "25/08/1930"}, 
            {"name": "agustina", "birthday": "17/11/1943"}]}
```

How can I take the information in 'people' without necessarily creating a new dictionary ? Because thats the only way I could do it. Here is my code:

```
import json

with open("cumple.txt", "r") as f: #cumple.txt is the file where my JSON is
    info = json.load(f)
l=[]
s=[]
print('we know the birthday of:')
for i in info['people']:
    print(i['name'])
    print(i['birthday'])
    l.append(i['name'])
    s.append(i['birthday'])

c=input("who's birthday want to know ? ")

dictionary = dict(zip(l, s))

if c in l:
    print('{} cumple el'.format(c), dictionary[c] )

else:
    print('we don\'t know the birthday of {}'.format(c)
```

Comment: If you know how to acces dictionary value, the the desired output is for you, make what you want

Comment: You should use `if c in dictionary`, not `if c in l`

Comment: Your code is not compiling. You are missing ```)``` at the end

Comment: Please be more specific about what the issue is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dictionary is generally the best way to do it. Without the dictionary you have to loop.

```
for i in info:
    if i['name'] == c:
        print('{} cumple el {}'.format(c, i['birthday']))
        break
else:
    print('we don\'t know the birthday of {}'.format(c)
```

The `else:` block of a `for` loop is executed when the loop ends normally instead of from `break`.